# How to tell if process is responding in Python on Windows

Tags: python, process, operating-system

I am writing a python script to keep a buggy program open and I need to figure out if the program is not respoding and close it on windows. I can't quite figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows you can do this:

```
import os
def isresponding(name):
    os.system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %s" /FI "STATUS eq running" > tmp.txt' % name)
    tmp = open('tmp.txt', 'r')
    a = tmp.readlines()
    tmp.close()
    if a[-1].split()[0] == name:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It is more robust to use the PID though:

```
def isrespondingPID(PID):
    os.system('tasklist /FI "PID eq %d" /FI "STATUS eq running" > tmp.txt' % PID)
    tmp = open('tmp.txt', 'r')
    a = tmp.readlines()
    tmp.close()
    if int(a[-1].split()[1]) == PID:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

From `tasklist` you can get more information than that. To get the "NOT RESPONDING" processes directly, just change "running" by "not responding" in the functions given. [See more info here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/796145).

Comment: Thanks, Quick question: How would I get the PID of the process I want if I'm putting it into a while loop (because I want it to run infintely and the PID might change because I'm going to close and reopen it)

Comment: @user2125510 If you are using `subprocess` to open the software (recommended) you can easily do like: `p = subprocess.Popen('calc.exe')` and access the PID with `PID=p.pid`

Comment: for my crashed and hanging application I get  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    isrespondingPID(9064)
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 6, in isrespondingPID
    if int(a[-1].split()[1]) == PID:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Es'`
I then just wrapped it in `try: ... except ValueError: ...`

Comment: @hardmooth we could also just search the corresponding name or PID in the file content. Might be easier. I have taken this approach for my solution.

Answer (score 4):

Piling up on the awesome answer from @Saullo GP Castro, this is a version using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system` to avoid creating a temporary file.

```py
import subprocess

def isresponding(name):
    """Check if a program (based on its name) is responding"""
    cmd = 'tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %s" /FI "STATUS eq running"' % name
    status = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    return name in str(status)
```

The corresponding PID version is:

```
def isresponding_PID(pid):
    """Check if a program (based on its PID) is responding"""
    cmd = 'tasklist /FI "PID eq %d" /FI "STATUS eq running"' % pid
    status = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    return str(pid) in str(status)
```

The usage of `timeit` showed that the usage of `subprocess.Popen` is twice as fast (mainly because we don't need to go through a file):

```
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
|          Function           | Time in s (10 iterations) |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
|       isresponding_os       |           8.902           |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
|     isrespondingPID_os      |           8.318           |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
|   isresponding_subprocess   |           4.852           |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
| isresponding_PID_subprocess |           4.868           |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Suprisingly, it is a bit slower for `os.system` implementation if we use PID but not much different if we use `subprocess.Popen`.

Hope it can help.